# Tiny MCE Editor issue on Joomla 1.5

Tags: javascript, joomla, tinymce, editor

I have a Joomla admin panel build on Joomla 1.5 , and it uses tinymce 2.12 . The problem with the editor occurs in chrome . Works fine in firefox.

Here is the Image of tiny MCE on Page load. 
[image]

When i Click on HTML it pops up the html editor . Image: 
[image]

As I press the update Button in popup , the tiny MCE edior turns out GREY and doesn't allow any editing .Image : [image]

Although on Save and Apply The content added in popup is saved properly . 
Can anyone help me out what is the issue with the Tiny MCE not performing well in CHROME ? is there any update of TinyMCE for joomla 1.5 ? I tried with tinyMCE 3 for Joomla 1.5 But that doesn't work .

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You should update TinyMCE to the latest version. You can just download the latest version from TinyMCE's official website and extract to the correct directory under Joomla. Make sure that you backup your Joomla website before and make sure that you delete the previous TinyMCE core files before uploading the new ones.